# connecting a java app to external microsoft sql server 2012

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have created a SQL server 2012 database. I need to connect to the database by using Java app created on another pc. this is my code but I cannot connect to the database, and I get error: "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows Authentication." (my code is working when both Java app and SQL server running on the same PC).
Appreciate your help.

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://THINKPADPC:1433;databaseName=TestDB;integratedSecurity=true;";

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sql server authentication. And pass username and password.

If you tryin windows authentication then it might be taking credentials from your(java) machine which has not been giving access on the hosted sql server machine.

Comment: Thanks for yout suggestion Godwin, I changed the string to "jdbc:sqlserver://THINKPADPC:1433;databaseName=TestDB;user:myUserName;password:myPass;", but now I'm getting "The connection string contains a badly formed name or value" error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Try this Connection and Change the ip, db , sa and password.

public class ConnectionClass {
    String ip = "192.168.0.131";
    String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String db = "Andro";
    String un = "sa";
    String password = "Admnsql1~";
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    try {
    Class.forName(classs);
    ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
    + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
    + password + ";";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
    Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
    }`enter code here`
}
```